# SQLite3 Date Ranges not working

Tags: sqlite

I cannot get date ranges to work properly in a query using SQLite3
Create And Populate Table:

```
create table dates(myDate DATE);
insert into dates values('2012-10-1');
insert into dates values('2012-10-2');
insert into dates values('2012-10-3');
insert into dates values('2012-10-4');
insert into dates values('2012-10-5');
insert into dates values('2012-10-6');
insert into dates values('2012-10-7');
insert into dates values('2012-10-8');
insert into dates values('2012-10-9');
insert into dates values('2012-10-10');
```

Query:

```
select * from dates where myDate >= '2012-10-1' and myDate < '2012-10-31';
```

Results:

```
2012-10-1
2012-10-2
2012-10-3
2012-10-10
```

Where are 10-4 - 10-9?

I get the same results if I use between:

```
select * from dates where myDate BETWEEN '2012-10-1' AND '2012-10-30';
```

If I change either of the queries to use '2012-11-1' as the end date, they work properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I solved the problem. Dates need to be in the format YYYY-MM-DD (not YYYY-MM-D)

Comment: Please put that not into a comment but into an answer.

Comment: The site won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours. Feel free to answer it for me!

Answer (score 2):

Date values must be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` with fixed-width fields.

This is required because SQLite has no native date format; to compare date strings correctly, fields with the same meaning must always be at the same position in the string.